# How can I load custom view Models for my application for different devices?

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, dpi

I am using below Jquery to get **dpi** for the browser window, and want to load **different layout models** on **different devices** for my app :

```
$("body").append("<div style='poosition:fixed;width:1cm;height:1cm;
'class='SCREENDPITEST'></div>")
var dpi = Math.floor($(".SCREENDPITEST").width() * 2.54);
)
```

And want to use **service** with below syntax :

```
 Fetch deviceCode /api/client/ui/device?dpi=96&height=1920&width=1080
```

Can anyone suggest what matrix should i follow to get layout models depending on above three properties. Or any new suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue with my application.There are few ways to overcome the problem:
1. You can use user agents to detect mobile devices :
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/03/mo-better-to-also-detect-mobile-user.html

But the problem with user agents is that they can be manipulated ( as its part of header).
So, if your app deals has security issue,I would not recommend it.
2. You can use few apps to detect device dppx and width of the screen. And then create your matrix for different devices and dppx and deduce that its a mobile or a desktop.

I would not recomment proceeding with DPIs.
You can get the reason on below blog pretty clearly : https://medium.com/@pixelthing/jonesing-for-dpi-and-dppx-45c6245f6ffc

Comment: looks like a approach. Thanks for the suggestion. Will definitely try to implement.